# Change namespace to Setting file

Tags: namespaces, settings

Is it possible to create a new folder in the project browser and move there the Setting file
 (The one which was created under the main namespace folder by default) ?

Do I have to change the configuration file itself (like to specify the new folder name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible :

1. From Properties file move the Settings (with its Settings.designer.cs) to the new folder.
2. Open the Settings.designer.cs file and change the namespace from `ApplicationName.Properties` to `NewFileName`.
3. In the app.config file, change the `<userSettings>
                              <ApplicationName.Properties.Settings>` places

   to                      `<userSettings>
   <NewFileName.Settings>`
4. Along the program use `NewFileName.Settings` instead of `Properties.Settings`.